# Basic SQL script

Tags: sql

So, I have to write a sql script to update 2 values on the same columns with a different ID from an ITEM table. Here is what I write:

```
UPDATE       ITEM
SET          ArtistName = 'Rex Baker'
WHERE        ItemNumber = 2
     AND     ItemNumber = 4;
```

However, it does not work at all. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong ? and how can I fix it ? Thank you

Comment: what you are saying is that the `item` must have an `ItemNumber` of `2 AND 4`... rather than `2 OR 4`.

Comment: I figured out how to do it. Basically, in the WHERE clause, I should put ItemNumber IN (2, 4);

Comment: @Secret Squirrel: So you can say OR instead of AND, and it works ?
PS: I tried OR and it works too ;)

Comment: @user2383193 The AND means that both conditions have to be met at the same time. `WHERE (ItemNumber = 2 AND ItemNumber = 4)` is an equivalent of your version. So, your item number will never have 2 different values on the same row, and thus nothing will happen in your script. I hope this shed some light on the question.

Comment: @user2383193 Using OR means that ONLY 1 condition has to be met by the record. So, if your row has either 2 or 4 in their ItemNumber column, then it will get updated.

Comment: @user2383193 just to be clear, the reason `OR` works too is because `IN(2,4)` means the `ItemNumber` is in this list... meaning the `ItemNumber` is `2 OR 4`. does this make sense?

Answer (score 8):

Use `or` or `in`

```
UPDATE   ITEM
SET      ArtistName = 'Rex Baker'
WHERE    ItemNumber = 2
OR       ItemNumber = 4;

UPDATE   ITEM
SET      ArtistName = 'Rex Baker'
WHERE    ItemNumber IN (2,4);
```